# jQuery :hover selector not working as expected in Edge and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a drag and drop system using sortable js in which you may delete the tiles by simply throwing them out of their container.
The issue is that although the code works for Chrome, it doesn't for Firefox, Edge or IE. 
The result in those three is that it never deletes the tile

link: http://skynet.ie/~alanfinnin/stack_overflow/js_drag_and_drop/

I've looked around for solutions in which I tried ..

1. changing opacity to 1 for all, no change
2. using different styles of hover, i.e. is(hover)
3. changing the color of the div when hovered over, which works but does not solve the problem

   ```
   onEnd: function(event) {            
       if (($('#lists:hover').length == 0)) {
           alert("delete");
       }
   }
   ```

I expect that when the tile is moved outside the div, the hover will change to 0 and the alert thrown, but instead, the result is always 0 in Firefox and Edge/IE as if it never left the div

Note: I'm working with IE 11 and firefox version 67.0.1

Comment: It looks like :hover is not support in IE and older versions of Firefox. https://caniuse.com/#search=hover

Comment: Im working with ie 11 and firefox 67.0., should probably edit to say that

Comment: @RemcoBravenboer The correct URL is https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2. The `:hover` selector has been supported for a very long time in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sortable offers you mouse position when onEnd event is triggered.

Since you have that and you have the container position and dimensions you can calculate yourself whether you are dropping in the container or outside of it. It will certainly work on all browsers since all we are doing are simple calculations.

The code you need is:

```
onEnd: function(event) {
    let mousePositionX = event.originalEvent.clientX; //mouse position x
    let mousePositionY = event.originalEvent.clientY; //mouse position y

     //container is the sortable container
     let container = $("div#lists");
     let containerOffsetLeft = parseInt(container.offset().left);
     let containerWidth = parseInt(container.width());
     let containerOffsetTop = parseInt(container.offset().top);
     let containerHeight = parseInt(container.height());

     if(
        (mousePositionY < containerOffsetTop) ||
        (mousePositionY > (containerOffsetTop + containerHeight)) ||
        (mousePositionX < containerOffsetLeft) ||
        (mousePositionX > (containerOffsetLeft + containerWidth))
     ) {
        alert('remove');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue Chrome's behavior is incorrect, or at least, more confusing than the one of the other implementations.

You are dragging a child of `#lists`, and as such you are obviously still hovering that dragged element. Since in the DOM this element is still a grand-child of `#lists`, it makes sense that `#list` still matches `:hover`, like how a parent is hovered when you do hover a fixed positioned child out of its bounds.

```css
#parent,#child {
  display: block; 
  width: 50%;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow: visible;
}
#parent {
  height: 75px;
}
#parent:hover {
 background: red; 
}
#child {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  I'm the child, hover over me
  </div>
</div>
```

Had you prevented the default behavior of the dragstart event (and thus the actual dragging of the Element), it would have done what you expected, but then you would have lost the *phantom* of the element.

So while I couldn't find any hack to achieve Chrome's behavior in every browser (tried cloning the element, changing its parent in dragstart some other tricks, nothing did...), one way to achieve what you want is to listen for the `dragexit`event on the `#lists` parent element. 
When this event fires, you can either set a class, or a js boolean to true, and remove it when the drag operation finished, or in `dragenter`. This way, you just have to check for this value, instead of only the `:hover` pseudo-class.

```js
(()=> {
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const dragme = document.getElementById('dragme');
const target = document.getElementById('target');  

parent.ondragexit = e => {
  // check it's not one of our children
  if(e.target === parent) {
    parent.classList.add('out');
  }
};
// remove the class
parent.ondragenter = document.ondragend = e => {
  parent.classList.remove('out');
}

dragme.ondragstart = e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');
};
target.ondrop = e => {
  target.append(dragme);
  dragme.ondragstart = null;
};
parent.ondragover = target.ondragover = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
};
})();
```

```css
#parent, #target, #dragme {
  border: 1px solid;
}
#parent, #target {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}
/* only if not .out */
#parent:hover:not(.out) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="dragme" class="dragclone" draggable="true">drag me</div>
</div>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

Comment: Im torn which one to mark as corect since both answers here work and explain things extremely well! I will say thank you very much for the answer as this was annoying me for quite a while :)